# Do I need I need to close SqlSession which create by SqlSessionFactory in Service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I want to to batch add user's role info, so i get mapper from sqlSessionFactory, so do I need to close the SqlSession after I used it?I don't know whether Spring will help me close the SqlSession.

```
public interface UserService{
    void insertRoleRelation(Long userId,List<Long> roleIdList);
}
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

     @Override
     public void insertRoleRelation(Long userId,List<Long> roleIdList) {
        SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH);
        UserRoleRelationMapper sessionUserRoleRelationMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(UserRoleRelationMapper.class);
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(roleIdList)) {
            roleIdList.forEach(i -> {
                //insert role relation
            });
        }
        sqlSession.flushStatements();
        //do I need to close sqlSession here?
        //sqlSession.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: When using MyBatis with Spring, you don't use `SqlSessionFactory`. See this [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html). This [demo](https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo) shows you how to setup/use batch and non-batch mappers in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for ave's comment,I find the easyest way to execute batch insert.you can see this article:

[how to use mybatis effectively perform batch db operations](http://pretius.com/how-to-use-mybatis-effectively-perform-batch-db-operations/)